# What is the relation between these two meanings of "theory"?

Tags: logic, terminology, model-theory

In [this introduction on Satisfiability modulo theories](http://disi.unitn.it/~rseba/papers/p02c12_smt.pdf), it is explained that by a "theory" $T$, it is meant a tuple $(\Sigma, I)$ where $\Sigma$ is a signature (i.e. a set of non-logical symbols), and $I$ is a set of models of signature $\Sigma$.

This is different from the definition of "theory" that I'm used to from mathematical logic, namely a set of $\Sigma$-formula's (i.e. axioms).

Essentially, the first definition is a **semantic** one and the second one is a **syntactic** one.

**Question:**

- From what context does the first definition come? Does it come from model theory? (which I don't know much about).
- What is the relation between the two?

Comment: Footnote 5 in the document you link to looks like the authors are aware their definition is not mainstream.

Comment: @HenningMakholm, I was aware of that footnote. I'd still like to know where this concept comes from and what the relation between the two is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've never seen the usage you mention before. Certainly if "theory" is said in a room full of mathematical logicians, unless someone says otherwise out loud everyone will assume it means either "set of sentences" or "*deductively closed* set of sentences." Occasionally specific contexts impose additional constraints - e.g. in model theory we often mean "*complete consistent* set of theories," and in computability theory we often mean "*countable* theory" - but $(i)$ those are understood as minor abuses of terminology and $(ii)$ they're still in the usual *context* of "theories = sets of sentences."

It's worth noting however - and this answers your first question - that every theory in the usual context corresponds to a theory of the type you describe: given a set of sentences $T$, we can look at the pair $(\Sigma,I)$ where $\Sigma$ is the language of $T$ and $I$ is the set of models of $T$. (This is mentioned in footnote $5$, which also points out that the usage here is nonstandard.) This makes that definition the (or at least *a*) right notion for ["semantic" abstract model theory](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.pl/1235417263), and  However, none of this contradicts the fact that **this is definitely a highly nonstandard usage**, and in any context where this meaning is used this will be stated explicitly.

As to where it comes from, the *notion* (as opposed to its name) is a natural one anytime logics other than first-order are considered; I imagine it either emerged in abstract model theory or in computer science (in the study of satisfiability over finite structures, where trans-first-order logics are actually quite important and "safe to use").

Comment: Do you happen to know whether the word "theory" in "satisfiability modulo theories" also is generally meant to be "set of sentences"?

Comment: @user600670 Yes. It's **everywhere** in mathematical logic generally meant to be "set of sentences," so far as I know; certainly in any of the circles I've travelled in (set theory, computability theory, model theory, and proof theory) to my experience.